# Change Output file name in AfterFX .jsx script

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-scripting, extendscript

I am rendering a project several times, and use a script to change some of the input. However, I have not figured out how to change the name of the output file in the script.

This is basically my script. I left the details of my modifying function out as they are irrelevant.

```js
app.beginSuppressDialogs();
{
    var projectFile File("C:\\AfterFX\\MyProject.aep");
    app.open(projectFile);
    MyCustomDataExchangeFunction();
    app.executeCommand(3800);
}
```

Comment: In case anybody is wondering, app.executeCommand(3800) sends the composition to the Adobe media encoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right property that has to be changed and wrote a function that does the job:

```js
function renameComposition(newName) {
    var curComp = null;
    for (var i = 1; i < app.project.numItems +1; i++) {
        if(app.project.item(i) instanceof CompItem) {
            curComp = app.project.item(i);
            curComp.name = newName;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware, though, that this changes teh names of every composition in your project to newName. That does not matter in my case, just fyi.